# Is there an extension in Visual Studio 2022 for automatic updates in your web application while developing?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm new to developing and it would be very helpful for me to see the impact of my code in real time, especially for front end. Are there any extensions to help me do this?

I know there is an extension in Visual Studio Code that does this, but it's not in VS 2022?

Comment: No need for any extension, visual studio has hot reload built in. It's the small fire icon in the toolbar. Either you click it when you did your changes or set it to auto update on save.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [HTML 11](https://vlasovstudio.com/html11/) extension.

When you change and save a page, Visual Studio recompiles it on save, updates the application on the fly, HTML 11 updates the preview and you see the updated page.